# Pelican plugins not found

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pelican

I am testing out Pelican for my personal blog use but I am stuck with the use of plugins.

Apparently, the `pelicanconf.py` file is not picking up my plugins.

Here's a snippet of my `pelicanconf.py`:

```
THEME = '/Users/namely/Public/MyPersonalWorkspace/static_blog/static-blog/pelican-themes/pelican-bootstrap3'


PLUGINS_PATHS = ["./plugins","plugins","./pelican-plugins","pelican-plugins","/Users/namely/Public/MyPersonalWorkspace/static_blog/static-blog/pelican-plugins"]
PLUGINS = ["sitemap"]
```

My pelican setup for theme is correct since I am using the theme correctly. But somehow, it is not reading my plugin directories. The following is my folder structure:

```
static-blog/
    content/
    output/
    pelican-plugins/
            sitemap/
                    __init__.py
                    sitemap.py
                    Readme.rst
   plugins/
          sitemap.py
   pelican-themes/
                  pelican-bootstrap3/
                                     # and all pelican-bootstrap3's files

   pelicanconf.py
   publishconf.py
   develop_server.sh
   fabfile
   Makefile
```

I am using Pelican 3.4, on a Macbook Air ( OSX 10.9.4 ), Python version 2.7.5

I am using a list of directories for `PLUGIN_PATHS` since all the directories didn't work ( either individually or in a list, relative or absolute. ).

My pelican installation is working fine since I can run my blog. It's just that the plugins are not working somehow. For plugins, I simply did a git clone from https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins.

The error message I received was:

```
ERROR: Can't find plugin `sitemap`: No module named sitemap
```

Any advice is great!

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be something as simple as a typo in your settings file. As noted in the [docs](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/plugins.html#plugins), the name of the relevant setting is `PLUGIN_PATHS`, whereas your settings file appears to contain `PLUGINS_PATHS` (note the spurious `S`).